# shiro custom filter conflict spring filter

Tags: spring-boot, filter, jwt, javabeans, shiro

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZqGp.png)

shiro anon lose efficacy

if I NOT use @bean Filter ,Filter---->service  is null

How Can I use custom filter shiro anon is use and filter inside  service is not null

Comment: Hey @andy_go, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You probably want to embed your code example in the question itself instead of linking out to an image.

Also, take a look at the Shiro Samples on GitHub: https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 0):

I checked your image of your code, and I was unable to find the service object which is null. 
I've already set up a project which integrates [Apache Shiro + Spring](http://ahmadsedi.com/Apache%20Shiro/Apache+Shiro+Spring+Integration.html), which may be helpful.